# Joining Enumerated and Symbol Column in kdb+ using Over

Tags: kdb

Im looking at two tables, one with an enumerated column the other is not. Im using (,/) to join them together and it doesn't unenumerate the data. (uj/) and last (,\) both do. Does anyone why this might be the case?

````
KDB+ 4.0 2021.04.26 Copyright (C) 1993-2021 Kx Systems

q)enum:`a`b
q)t1:([]c1:`enum$`a`b)
q)t2:([]c1:`a`b)
q)(,/) (t1;t2)
c1
--------
`enum$`a
`enum$`b
`a
`b
q)(uj/) (t1;t2)
c1
--
a
b
a
b
q)last(,\) (t1;t2)
c1
--
a
b
a
b
q)```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect it's because `,/` (along with `raze`) is given special treatment by the interpreter while the others aren't.

An actual append-over gives you the result you want:

```
q)0N!({x,y}/)(t1;t2);
+(,`c1)!,`a`b`a`b
```

So even though `{x,y}/` appears to be the same as `,/`, that isn't always the case due to the "special treatment" under the covers

Comment: Honestly Terry thats what I was thinking aswell similar to how select date from partitionedTable has optimizations associated with it aswell but I wanted to see if I was missing anything. Thanks for the ({x,y)}/) though!